# How to use private frameworks in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, iphone-privateapi

I am trying to use private frameworks in my app which is not going to app store. Can anyone guide me, how to use private headers generated using class-dump in my ios application.

Below link is listing some private frameworks generated using class-dump. I am trying to import SringBoardServices.h in my MyClass.m file, but i am unable to access it. I am creating an object to SringBoardServices.h like 
**SringBoardServices** ***ref** = [[**SringBoardServices** **alloc**]**init**];
and trying to access it's methods like ref.method_name. Whether it is a right approach to use private frameworks?
**LINK**: [private-frameworks](https://github.com/Cykey/ios-reversed-headers/tree/master/SpringBoardServices)

I tried using Class myclass = NSClassFromString(@"SpringBoardServices");
              id myobj = [[myclass alloc] init];  , but unable to access SpringBoardServices methods.

Comment: see more about `NSClassFromString`

Comment: copy that .h file into your project.  then #import it normally.  then, add the private framework under your project's Build Phases (you'll find it under the xcode install dir, under PrivateFrameworks for iphoneos).  otherwise, it's just like using public APIs.

Comment: @Nate I tried Class myclass = NSClassFromString(@"SpringBoardServices");
 id myobj = [[myclass alloc] init]; , but unable to access SpringBoardServices methods.

Comment: What do mean exactly by "unable to access"? Check NSClassFromString return value - may be it returns NULL in which case you probably forgot to link private framework (read Nate's comment above).